# Why in karate if a key does not exist the test pass

Tags: karate

I do not understand why this test does not fail

```
* def resp = {result:[]}

* math each resp.result[*].fakeKey == 'pippo'
```

the key **fakeKey** does not exist, so why the match does not throw error?
Thanks